# angular RouterLinkActive not matching child paths

Tags: angular, navbar, routerlinkactive

I am relatively new to Angular and am trying to get a highlight to work on my NavBar. I have been through some other articles but they are not quite helping.

In my **app-routing.ts** file

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
 { path: 'guided-trades', component: GuidedTradeComponent },
 { path: 'guided-trade-detail/:id', component: GuidedTradeDetailComponent }, 
 { path: "**", redirectTo: '/dashboard'}
];
```

In my **app.component.html** file

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a id="positions" class="nav-link" routerLink="/positions" routerLinkActive="active">Positions</a>
  </li>         
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a id="guidedtrades" class="nav-link" routerLink="/guided-trades" routerLinkActive="navlinkactive">Guided Trades</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

in my **guides-trade.component.ts** file I have list which when a row is clicked navigates me to the detail record for that item (this works fine and I get to the correct page)

```
onRowClicked(row) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/guided-trade-detail/' + row.recID);
}
```

in my **styles.css** file

```
.navlinkactive {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #007dba;
 }
```

When I click *Guides Trades* from the Nav Bar it highlights correctly. However, what I would like is that if I have navigated to the Guided Trade detail record the Guides Trades Nav Item is still highlighted. I have played around with trying children routes in the app-routing.ts file but I just can't get it to work.

Would it just be easier to add something like [ngClass]="{'active': guidedtradedetail.isActive }" to the navlink in the **app.component.html** file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the [`routerLinkActiveOptions`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#routerLinkActiveOptions) exact setting to `false`

```
<div routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: false}">
```

Comment: Thanks I hadn't tried that. I think I had spent so much time on it the answer was staring me in the face. I ended up changing the entries in **app-routing.ts** to :   { path: 'guided-trades', component: GuidedTradeComponent },
  { path: 'guided-trades/:id', component: GuidedTradeDetailComponent }, and everything now works as I wanted

Comment: Glad to help. If this managed to solve your issue, would you mind marking is as solved using the green tick button? That way others with the same issue can find the solution. Thanks